# Update to revision does not work for relative externals

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

The directory test_externals contains a real file "original.txt" and an external originating from it:
../test_externals/original.txt external.txt

An "update to revision" to a former revision does not select the former revision for the external.txt. Here evidence from the command line:

```
D:\test_externals>dir
27.06.2019  16:33    <DIR>          .
27.06.2019  16:33    <DIR>          ..
27.06.2019  16:27                 8 external.txt
27.06.2019  16:27                 8 original.txt
               2 Datei(en),             16 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 128.625.299.456 Bytes frei

D:\test_externals>svn ls
original.txt

D:\test_externals>svn pg svn:externals .
../test_externals/original.txt external.txt

D:\test_externals>svn info external.txt |findstr Revision
Revision: 578

D:\test_externals>svn info original.txt |findstr Revision
Revision: 578

D:\test_externals>svn update -r 577
Updating '.':
U    original.txt

Fetching external item into 'external.txt':
Updated external to revision 578.

At revision 577.

D:\test_externals>svn info external.txt |findstr Revision
Revision: 578

D:\test_externals>svn info original.txt |findstr Revision
Revision: 577
```

I would have expected that external.txt should also be updated to revision 577.
I used:

```
TortoiseSVN 1.11.1, Build 28492 - 64 Bit , 2019/01/08 21:40:39
ipv6 enabled
Subversion 1.11.1, -release
apr 1.6.5
apr-util 1.6.1
serf 1.3.9
OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018
zlib 1.2.11
SQLite 3.23.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would have expected that external.txt should also be updated to revision 577

Wrong. In your definition you don't use PEG-revision, thus it will be always HEAD (AFAICR). Re-read SVN Book sections [Externals Definitions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html) + [Peg and Operative Revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html)

Comment: From SVN book: "Note that even when you don't explicitly supply a peg revision or operative revision, they are still present. For your convenience, the default peg revision is BASE for working copy items and HEAD for repository URLs. And when no operative revision is provided, it defaults to being the same revision as the peg revision." And here the definition of the externals from from the SVN book: "the optional revision flags come first, then the external Subversion repository URL, and finally the relative local subdirectory"

Comment: @Trulli - and you'll get HEAD (always HEAD, as written).